# zlib is missing which break Haxe and pip on Mac OS X 10.11 (El Capitan)

Tags: macos, python, homebrew, pip, osx-el-capitan

I upgraded to El Capitan (version 10.11 Beta 7, build 15A263e) a few days ago. Aside from issues related to permissions, everything seemed to work fine. However, when I try to run some Haxe libraries, or use the Python package manager pip, I get errors related to `zlib`, which I'm not sure how to resolve.

The Haxe error occurs when I try to run `haxelib run lime setup`, and I get this:

```
Called from /usr/lib/haxe/std/neko/_std/haxe/zip/Compress.hx line 60
Uncaught exception - load.c(237) : Failed to load library : zlib.ndll (dlopen(zlib.ndll, 1): image not found)
```

When I try to run pip, which I installed via Homebrew, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('pip==7.1.2', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 558, in load_entry_point
return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2682, in load_entry_point
return ep.load()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2355, in load
return self.resolve()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2361, in resolve
module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 10, in <module>
from pip.download import path_to_url
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 38, in <module>
from pip._vendor import requests, six
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
from . import utils
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/utils.py", line 26, in <module>
from .compat import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/compat.py", line 7, in <module>
from .packages import chardet
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from . import urllib3
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
from .connectionpool import (
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 38, in <module>
from .response import HTTPResponse
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 5, in <module>
import zlib
ImportError: No module named zlib
```

This is in addition to permissions errors with pip; I can't run pip without using `sudo`, but I think that's probably unrelated.

Any thoughts? I think that building the missing the `zlib.ndll` might fix the issue, but I don't know what the "right" way to do that is.

Comment: I was able to fix the pip issues with [this](http://andinfinity.de/quick-note-homebrew-installed-python-fails-to-import-zlib/), but Haxe is still funky.

Answer (score 2):

Haxe requires neko to be configured correctly to run tools like haxelib. You can install neko via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) with the following steps. First you need zlib and sqlite because neko requires both.

```
brew install zlib sqlite3
```

You will now need to force Homebrew to link these since they are keg-only libraries and neko needs the include files in /usr/local/include.

```
brew link zlib --force
brew link sqlite3 --force
```

Finally, install neko through Homebrew. Make sure you also set NEKOPATH to the homebrew directory created.

```
brew install neko --HEAD
```

Comment: The error Steve is getting is related to neko not being configured properly for Haxe. I updated my answer.